# Checkboxes aligned on row

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have multiple checkboxes and everyone is displayed on a row. I want to have 3 or 4 checkboxes on a row, but I can't do it.
Angular:

```
<div class="form">
     <mat-label>Choose skills:</mat-label>
     <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let skill of listOfSkills; index as i" id="skills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="getSkill($event,i)">{{skill}}
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container input[type=checkbox]{
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You can wrap the checkboxes in a flex div with flex-direction as row. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your question, maybe I can understand as you try to align all checkbox inside a container `div` ? Not sure is this what you looking for ?

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

input{
  margin-right:10px;
}
input:last-child{
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" />
   <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Somethign like that. Thank you. I succeeded with: ```display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  max-width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;```

Comment: you are welcome, can hv a upvote for me , thx =)

Answer (score 0):

Your css sets the `display` property to `inline-block` on the `input` tag, but the surrounding `div` tag is still a block element and therefore will always wrap.

Your css should look like this:

css:

```
.container .checkbox {
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="form">
    <mat-label>Choose skills:</mat-label>
    <div class="container">
        <div *ngFor="let skill of listOfSkills; index as i" class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="getSkill($event,i)">{{skill}}
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Every checkbox has it's own row.